# How do I send an email confirmation link to the user

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, confirmation-email

I am developing a website where I need to send confirmation link to the user's e-mail account when he/she signs-up.

When user clicks this link then a field `userEnable` in database changes from *"false"* to *"true".*

How do I send a confirmation e-mail to a user when user clicks on the signup button.

When user clicks on this confirmation link then how would the field `UserEnable` change from *"false"* to *"true"*

I am using asp.net 4.0 with VB.NET as the language and SQL Server 2008 for my database.

Comment: The fact that you want people here to just give you a full solution is not going to be taken well. Show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should create table User in database with a column like `Active = false` in database (1 bit database field type).
Then, after user has created his account, you should send him an activation link with query string containing user activation guid.
Something like:

> Please activate your account at
>   www.mysite.com?id=21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D

At confirmation page, you will check for this query like

```
var id = Response.QueryString["id"]
if (id!= null) userBL.ActivateUser(id);
```

ActivateUser() method would update field to true, and also send an email confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

The answer posted by nemke is good, but I do it slightly differently and I feel it is a bit more secure and protected against future changes. I create two extra fields for confirmation in each of my user records when they are created in the database.

Something like the following fields for each user:

```
userID: getUniqueUserID()
confirmed: false,
confirmCode: getRandomUUID()
```

The `confirmCode` is kept separate from the unique `userID` for each record and should only ever be used when the email is sent to the address used in registration. I then send a URL like the following:

http://example.com/activate?id=43d24b9ca73&c=16b4cf80-c59a-11e2-8b8b-0800200c9a66

You can then get the query fields server side and use the `id` in order look up the particular user record based on the unique `userID`, make sure the the `c` field matches `confirmCode` in the record, and then set the `confirmed` field to true and save the particular user's record in the database.

Comment: I agree that guid should not be UserId, but an additional guid. It's better for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

### Users

ID | Username | Email | UserEnabled

to send E-mail check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/epsendmail.aspx).

When you receive the confirmation link, you do a lookup based on the Email field and the set its corresponding UserEnabled to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ASP.NET Built in Membership Controls you can use the

**[MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx)** property of the **[CreateUserWizard Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.maildefinition.aspx)**

> The MailDefinition property returns a
>   reference to a group of properties
>   that you use to define the format and
>   content of the e-mail message that is
>   sent to new users. Common settings
>   include the subject line and the
>   sender's return address.